# angular-google-analytics Missing Tracking Code

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics

I'm using 'angular-google-analytics' ( https://github.com/revolunet/angular-google-analytics).

Below you can find the configuration I've used.

I'm getting Analytics Notification -  "missing tracking code". Probably I've done something wrong...

Can someone advice, what could be wrong?

```js
angular.module('myModule', ['angular-google-analytics']);

.....
// The configuration is as below 
AnalyticsProvider.logAllCalls(true).startOffline(true).useECommerce(true, true);
        AnalyticsProvider.setAccount('UA-XXXXXXX-1');
        AnalyticsProvider.setDomainName('mywebsite.net');      AnalyticsProvider.setHybridMobileSupport(true);

.....

// in Controllers, Analytics is injected as below
function UserItemsController($scope, $rootScope,  Analytics) {
    ....

    Analytics.trackPage('/user/' + $scope.currentUserName);
    Analytics.pageView();
}
```

Comment: I suppose you have updated `AnalyticsProvider.setAccount('UA-XXXXXXX-1');` with your own account?

Comment: Yep, I did it. The same for AnalyticsProvider.setDomainName

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved. I'd like to share the solution here, perhaps someone will find it useful.

To resolve the issue, I've added the next script (provided by google) to my code. Note, it's not mentioned in the documentation of the  'angular-google-analytics', that it's mandatory to add the code, and it might be very confusing.

```js
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Comment: Why is that the solution? On the [Angulartics GitHub page](http://angulartics.github.io/) they explicitly mention to leave out the `ga('send', 'pageview');`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to add google analytics code for your website/app.

To do so, Please visit below link:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en

Hope it helps you.

Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help.
I've used 

AnalyticsProvider.setAccount('UA-XXXXXXX-1');  to set the analytics code provided by Google. I'll try to use Google Tag Manager for troubleshooting, perhaps it will shed the light .

Comment: Replace your generated google analytic code instead of `UA-XXXXXXX-1` : AnalyticsProvider.setAccount('UA-XXXXXXX-1');